# Can I use Foreign Data Wrapper for SQL Server in Windows Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, windows-server, foreign-data

I use PostgreSQL and SQL Server. I want to get SQL Server data in PostgreSQL.

I found [PostgreSQL Foreign Data Wrapper](https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw). There are installation packs for CentOS and Ubuntu. However, I want to use FDW in Windows Server 2012.

How can I use FDW? Or what is another way to get SQL Server data in PostgreSQL?

Comment: The [BigSQL](https://www.bigsql.org/package-manager.jsp) project has a package manager where you can download Windows binaries for TDS FDW. The URL for the binaries is: http://s3.amazonaws.com/pgcentral/tds_fdw1-pg96-1.0.8-1-win64.tar.bz2